# Python Selenium Select date in calendar for start date and end date

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I am trying to select start date and end date from the datepicker, and I tried for start date:

```
driver.get('http://www.chinamoney.com.cn/chinese/zjfxzx/?tbnm=%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0&tc=null&isNewTab=1')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.refresh()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
datefield = driver.find_element_by_id('pdbp-date-1').send_keys("2021-01-05")
```

But calendar just drop down but does not click, how could I select the start date and then end date from the calendar? besides how could it wait until calendar element shows up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the rest of your code? If I run your code as is, the field isn't even visible.

Comment: the website loaded so slow, you could refresh it or just copy the website first, I am not sure how to wait until the element shows up..

Comment: That isn't the issue. The website is detecting that you are using automated browsing and purposely not loading that section.

Comment: I refresh manually  it will load finally

Comment: I amended the code, and refresh it , should be fine to locate the element now

Comment: @goalie1998 if you want the testable code you can use the bottom to bypass the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding an useragent causes it work correctly. Goalie was hinting at bot detection and it wasn't running the Jquery.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Here's a random useragent

```
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2919.83 Safari/537.36")
```

Now to the code. If it's a JQuery date picker object you have to click and select your date. Year->Month->Day is the order you want to click. If you aren't allowed to use Select then just click the tag and xpath down to the options whose value is 1 or text is your value. /option[text()='January'] and so forth.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get('http://www.chinamoney.com.cn/chinese/zjfxzx/?tbnm=%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0&tc=null&isNewTab=1')
datefield = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pdbp-date-1")))
datefield.click()
##<select class="ui-datepicker-year" data-handler="selectYear" data-event="change"></select>
select = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("2020")
##<select class="ui-datepicker-month" data-handler="selectMonth" data-event="change"></select>
select2 = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
select2.select_by_value("1")
day=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a[text()='{}']".format(str(day))))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks but currently I cannot install that package, so is is that possible just use selenium? but still the calendar wont click the date, just calendar drop down

Comment: Oh just add any user-agent.

Comment: Thanks it worked! but when I jump to end date I tried `datefield_ed = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pdbp-date-2")))
datefield_ed.click()
select_ed = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
select_ed.select_by_visible_text("2021")
select2 = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
select2.select_by_value("2")
day=2
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@data-handler='selectDay']/a[text()='{}']".format(str(day))))).click()` after the code, but says cannot locate 2

Comment: Months start at value 0 and 2021 only has 0,1 so far. Just wrap the selects in try and except.

Comment: Hi Arundeep, could you please help me check why this cannot work when I select date: end date cant click `datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start_date")))
datefield_st.click()
day=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr/td[text()='{}']".format(str(day))))).click()
datefield_ed = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "end_date")))
datefield_ed.click()
day_ed=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr/td[text()='{}']".format(str(day_ed))))).click()`  website is http://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/bond/announcement/company/

Comment: Is it just the day? Can you post it in a question.

Comment: would be great if month could be selected..if no, it's ok to go just with day thank you for your help